# Chapter bibliography not displaying

Tags: bibliographies

In the preamble of main file

```
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  
\usepackage{chapterbib}
```

In tex file "A" - Chapter A

```
aaaaaa \cite{bibtexkey1}

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{bib file A}
```

In tex file "B" - Chapter B

```
aaaaaa \cite{bibtexkey2}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{bib file B}
```

In tex file "C" - Chapter C

```
aaaaaa \cite{bibtexkey13}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{bib file C}
```

Compiling result:

1. End of Chapter A Fully displayed cite references in `bib file A`
2. In pdf display question mark in text and at the end of Chapter B Fully displayed cite references in `bib file A`
3. The same result of references display as chapter B

Questions:
Could you please help me to solve the issue? Many thanks

P/s: I have tried several ways, but still not work.

Comment: Natbib is outdated. Can you give biblatex a try?

Comment: Natbib is not outdated

Comment: On the other hand, this is much easier with the modern package `biblatex`.

Comment: I tried, but I did work. Here what I coded

Comment: \usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Chapter 1.bib, Chapter 2.bib} then in each chapter \begin{refsection}  \cite{bibtexID} \printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc]
\end{refsection} \end{document}

Comment: but it not displaying again.

Comment: Please your kindly help me!

Comment: in specific, this is the error notification " Missing } inserted. \end{refsection} " Please help me, many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Referring to your comments I assume that you want a bibliography at the end of each chapter using biblatex and biber. Important is the option `refsection=chapter` combined with the heading `subbibliography` at the `\printbibliography` command in each chapter.

You can compile the example code below by:

1. pdflatex document.tex
2. biber document
3. pdflatex document.tex
4. pdflatex document.tex

---

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{bibch1.bib}
@article{hamid2011potential,
    title={Potential risk factors associated with human encephalitis: application of canonical correlation analysis},
    author={Hamid, Jemila S and Meaney, Christopher and Crowcroft, Natasha S and Granerod, Julia and Beyene, Joseph},
    journal={BMC medical research methodology},
    volume={11},
    number={1},
    pages={120},
    year={2011},
    publisher={BioMed Central}
}
@article{hattie1985methodology,
    title={Methodology review: assessing unidimensionality of tests and ltenls},
    author={Hattie, John},
    journal={Applied psychological measurement},
    volume={9},
    number={2},
    pages={139--164},
    year={1985},
    publisher={Sage Publications Sage CA: Thousand Oaks, CA}
}
@article{kirk1973numerical,
    title={On the numerical approximation of the bivariate normal (tetrachoric) correlation coefficient},
    author={Kirk, David B},
    journal={Psychometrika},
    volume={38},
    number={2},
    pages={259--268},
    year={1973},
    publisher={Springer}
}
@article{lee2015access,
    title={Access to finance for innovative SMEs since the financial crisis},
    author={Lee, Neil and Sameen, Hiba and Cowling, Marc},
    journal={Research policy},
    volume={44},
    number={2},
    pages={370--380},
    year={2015},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{bibch2.bib}
@article{samuel2015effect,
    title={The effect of credit risk on the performance of commercial banks in Nigeria},
    author={Samuel, Olawale Luqman},
    journal={African Journal of Accounting, Auditing and Finance},
    volume={4},
    number={1},
    pages={29--52},
    year={2015},
    publisher={Inderscience Publishers (IEL)}
}
@article{froot1998risk,
    title={Risk management, capital budgeting, and capital structure policy for financial institutions: an integrated approach},
    author={Froot, Kenneth A and Stein, Jeremy C},
    journal={Journal of Financial Economics},
    volume={47},
    number={1},
    pages={55--82},
    year={1998},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{salas2002credit,
    title={Credit risk in two institutional regimes: Spanish commercial and savings banks},
    author={Salas, Vicente and Saurina, Jesus},
    journal={Journal of Financial Services Research},
    volume={22},
    number={3},
    pages={203--224},
    year={2002},
    publisher={Springer}
}
@article{cornett2011liquidity,
    title={Liquidity risk management and credit supply in the financial crisis},
    author={Cornett, Marcia Millon and McNutt, Jamie John and Strahan, Philip E and Tehranian, Hassan},
    journal={Journal of Financial Economics},
    volume={101},
    number={2},
    pages={297--312},
    year={2011},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{aebi2012risk,
    title={Risk management, corporate governance, and bank performance in the financial crisis},
    author={Aebi, Vincent and Sabato, Gabriele and Schmid, Markus},
    journal={Journal of Banking \& Finance},
    volume={36},
    number={12},
    pages={3213--3226},
    year={2012},
    publisher={Elsevier}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{texch1.tex}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[2-3]
\nocite{hamid2011potential, hattie1985methodology, kirk1973numerical,%
lee2015access}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{texch2.tex}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\lipsum[2-3]
\nocite{samuel2015effect, froot1998risk, salas2002credit, cornett2011liquidity,%
aebi2012risk}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, refsection=chapter]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibch1.bib}
\addbibresource{bibch2.bib}

\begin{document}

\include{texch1}

\include{texch2}

\end{document}
```

---

This is what you get:

[image: The result]